# Setter for a field of a field

Tags: python, getter-setter

Given the code:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Block:
    size = 40

    def __init__(self, x=1, y=1):
        self.pixel_position = Point(x * Block.size, y * Block.size)
        self.__block_position = Point(x, y)

    @property
    def block_position(self):
        return self.__block_position

    @block_position.setter
    def block_position(self, point):
        #I want for pixel_position to be updated whenever block position changes
        self.pixel_position.x += point.x * size
        self.pixel_position.y += point.y * size 
        self.__block_position = point
```

Now for such code simple assignment works well

```
block = Block()
block.block_position = Point(2, 1)
```

but if I want to increment `x` of `block position`... well, code doesn't go into setter.

```
block.block_position.x -= 1
# now block_position = (1, 1) but pixel_position = (80, 40) not (40, 40)
```

How may I change it?

I know I can resolve this problem with adding property for `__pixel_position` that will calculate `Block.size * __block_position` before returning itself, but that approach doesn't satisfy me - well I want to know how in python one can set a property for a field of a field.

My question is not about finding any solution, but to find a solution where changing field `block_position.x` will redirect me to my setter/getter.

Comment: Just define a @setter on Point class for the "x" property. Why not add two more attributes to that class, "pixel_x", "pixel_y"?

Comment: if I define setter for x in Point, how will it know about the size of the block?

Comment: in the setter that you define in the Point class you could pass the "size" as an additional argument. for e.g. you could pass a dict or array as the value to the setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for it, I'm providing an example implementation where properties of an object notify their owner when being set, for it to synchronize with another object. I only consider 1D points (`x`) in this example since the implementation for `y` is the very same:

```
class NotificationProperty(property):
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None, notify=None):
        super().__init__(fget, fset, fdel, doc)
        self.notify = notify

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __set__(self, instance, val):
        super().__set__(instance, val)
        self.notify(instance, self.name, val)

    # Should define similar methods for other attributes
    # (see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties).
    def setter(self, fset):
        return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__, self.notify)


def notification_property(func):
    from functools import partial
    return partial(NotificationProperty, notify=func)


class SyncPoint:
    def __init__(self, x, sync_with=None):
        self.sync_with = sync_with
        self.x = x

    def sync(self, which, value):
        if self.sync_with is not None:
            obj, scale = self.sync_with
            value = int(scale * value)
            if getattr(obj, which) != value:  # Check if already synced -> avoid RecursionError.
                setattr(obj, which, value)

    @notification_property(sync)
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self._x = val


class Block:
    size = 40

    def __init__(self, x=1):
        self.pixel_position = SyncPoint(self.size * x)
        self.block_position = SyncPoint(x, sync_with=(self.pixel_position, self.size))
        self.pixel_position.sync_with = (self.block_position, 1/self.size)


block = Block(3)
print('block_pos: ', block.block_position.x)  # block_pos:  3
print('pixel_pos: ', block.pixel_position.x)  # pixel_pos:  120

block.block_position.x -= 1
print('block_pos: ', block.block_position.x)  # block_pos:  2
print('pixel_pos: ', block.pixel_position.x)  # pixel_pos:  80

block.pixel_position.x -= Block.size
print('block_pos: ', block.block_position.x)  # block_pos:  1
print('pixel_pos: ', block.pixel_position.x)  # pixel_pos:  40
```

#### Variation: specify the notify function via `x.setter(func)`

The following is a variation of the above code which let's you specify the function to be called for notifications during definition of `x.setter`. This might feel more intuitive since the notification happens on `__set__` but in the end it's a matter of taste:

```
from functools import partial


class notification_property(property):
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None, notify=None):
        super().__init__(fget, fset, fdel, doc)
        self.notify = notify

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __set__(self, instance, val):
        super().__set__(instance, val)
        self.notify(instance, self.name, val)

    # Should define similar methods for other attributes
    # (see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties).
    def setter(self, func=None):
        return partial(type(self), self.fget, fdel=self.fdel, doc=self.__doc__, notify=(func or self.notify))


class SyncPoint:
    def __init__(self, x, sync_with=None):
        self.sync_with = sync_with
        self.x = x

    def sync(self, which, value):
        if self.sync_with is not None:
            obj, scale = self.sync_with
            value = int(scale * value)
            if getattr(obj, which) != value:  # Check if already synced -> avoid RecursionError.
                setattr(obj, which, value)

    @notification_property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter(sync)
    def x(self, val):
        self._x = val
```

Comment: awesome! thats exactly what I was looking for. Now seeing it I do get that 90% of the time if I have to use such solutions its poor design of an app, but anyway - thats exactly mechanism I was looking forward to learn!

Comment: I did not include a design like this in my answer, because it is easy to get lost on the way to configure this properly - 2 way for each property - so I made my answer advising you to keep it one way. I keep that it would be safer. BTW - this code does not do that bothways, it just provides a complicated way to to eager computing of the attribute - I would not advise using it.

Comment: @jsbueno I totally agree with you, I advice against its usage as well (at least for the OP's purpose). Instead I prefer the approach which I've outlined in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504703/3767239) (which is similar to what you wrote in your answer). For educational purposes, on the other hand, this way of handling things might be insightful nevertheless. And to be fair, it is what the OP asked for (well not precisely but with some slight modifications one can also call the instance's setter directly). It is different from eager computation since one can set `_x` directly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem there is that you are mixing some concepts trying to make use of Python `property` and things get confusing  -

The basic thing is that if `pixel_position` is to be to be calculated - it should itself a property.

What your are trying to do is to put some gates on the setting of values on "block_position" and derive - when block_position is changed the new value for pixel_position. That is not working because you have not "gatted" always one could possibly modify the values inside your block_position.

What happens when you make:

```
 block.block_position.x += 1
```

Is that the property `getter` for block_position is activated - the Point object in there then have its `x` attribute changed - but this change never goes through the outter block object,as `x` is an ordinay attribute, not  a property.

Now, it would be *possible* to instrument your `Point` class so that actions could be triggered whenever `x` ou `y` are changed - but that could become really complicated, and fast.

A better approache there is to have pixel_position itself be a property, instead of an ordinary attribute, and have its values lazily calculated - generated whenever they are needed - and not depend on the value to be setted eagerly whenever block_position changes.  This is a pattern from "reactive programing".
Actually, you will find out that "block_poisition" itself can be an ordinary instance attribute, and not be a property - unless you want its checker to ensure the assigned object is an instance of  `Point`.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __mul__(self, scale):
        return Point(self.x * scale, self.y * scale)


class Block:
    size = 40
    def __init__(self, x=1,y=1):
        self._block_position = Point(x,y)
    @property
    def block_position(self):
        return self._block_position

    @block_position.setter
    def block_position(self, point):
        if not isinstance(point, Point):
            # raise TypeError()  # or, as an option, accept sequences of 2 coordinates:
            point = Point(point[0], point[1])

        self._block_position = point

    @property
    @pixel_position(self):
        return self._block_position * self.size
```

So, now things are the other way around - and pixel_position can't be setted and is guaranteed to be always updated.

Three things in there:

- I've added the `__mul__` method to your Point so now one can just use the `*` operator to multiply it by a scalar.
- There is no need or sense in actually prepending `__` to Python "hidden" attributes. Early tutorials or unofficial documentation to the language could misleadingly say it is a way of having "private attributes". That is an error - there is no private attributes in Python what `__` does is name mangling in order to allow a class to have attributes that are not messed up by subclasses. In almost 20 years of Python programming I've never actually needed that feature. On the other hand, it *can* give you strange errors if you have subclasses of `Block`. Just don't. The accepted convention is that one single "_" indicates an attribute that should not be changed or accessed directly by users of the class and this have no side effects.
- Without a setter, `pixel_position` is mostly "unchangeable" - and if one does change the attributes inside it after retrieving  `block.pixel_position` , he will be changing a detached Point instance.

If you really need round-trip changing between pixel_position and block_position (that is, make in such a way the class user can change either attribute and have the change reflected in the other), rather than trying to instrument a change notification inside  `Point` , I suggest you make `Point` an immutable class instead.  Anyone wanting to change coordinates would have to create a new point instance - as a result `block.block_position.x += 1` would not work anymore - one would have to do: `block.block_position += Point(1, 0)`  (and then you implement `__add__` in Point, just as I did `__mul__`). Then you could write your setter for `pixel_position` to force a new value to `block_position` if it gets changed.

On the upside, if you make Point immutable, you can add `__hash__` to it and have it working in sets and as dictionary keys: a lot of other uses open up.

Check the `class V2` implementation on [this project](https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/blob/46a2c861d0dff773f4c91dde25115e20b073688d/terminedia.py#L608) to have an idea of a nice implementation (Disclaimer: the link project is something I am working now as a hobby, and I have actually implemented this class over the past week)

Comment: well this answers my question to the full extent,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by making `pixel_position` a property since this attribute seems dependent on the other, `block_position`. That way `block_position` doesn't even have to be a property:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.x}, {self.y})'

class Block:
    size = 40
    def __init__(self, x=1, y=1):
        self.block_position = Point(x,y)

    @property
    def pixel_position(self):
        return Point(self.block_position.x * self.size, self.block_position.y * self.size)

block = Block()
block.block_position = Point(2,1)
block.block_position.x -= 1
print(block.block_position)  # Point(1, 1)
print(block.pixel_position)  # Point(40, 40)
```

In general dependent attributes are suitable for properties as they can be computed "on-the-fly" from other, independent ones.

Comment: this will work for the code I showed here (as I have written on the bottom of my question) I'd like to know how to acces setter inside Block class when asigning to a field block.block_position.x . 
My real example inherits pixel_position from other classes without any setters or getter thus overriding inherited property would be similar pain in the ass

Comment: @Yurkee That's not possible unless `block_position` keeps a reference to `block` and you update it therein. `block.block_position.x` will invoke `Block.block_position.__get__(block, type(block))` and hence the setter is skipped altogether. In case `x` is a property of `Point` then the corresponding setter will be called with the `block_position` instance. But then this instance has no idea of `block` which you would like to update as well. I'm sure you could achieve this with some weird usage of [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) but I don't recommend to do so.